# WebMatrix 2 freezes when trying to open existing Node site

Tags: node.js, webmatrix

I have an existing Node project sitting in my Dropbox, and when I open it in WebMatrix 2, it detects it as a Node project but then freezes on 'Configuring Site'.

Any ideas on how I could diagnose what is causing this?

Comment: had the same issue I alwas stuck with detecting settings for IISExpress so +1 vote up for a solution =)

Comment: Yikes.  Could you do us a huge favor?  After the hang, can you go to the event viewer (eventvwr.exe), and look for an error in the application event log?

Comment: I am not seeing anything related to WebMatrix other than installation (and un-installation when I removed and re-installed trying to fix the issue).  To be clear, I'm looking in Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application.

Comment: Next thing to try :-)  Could I get a screen shot of the freeze?  I think the only thing we do during that step is install an extension called WebMatrixConfig - it's a really strange place to freeze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else that runs into this - it was a problem with our online feed.  We made a fix, and everything should start to work now.  If you're still running into issues, please delete all of the files in %localappdata%\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\ and try again.

Comment: Hi Justin - I'm stuck as well. Tried your suggestion, deleted all files in said folder - twice, and still not working. It seems to be looking for a file called GenericNodeApp.zip, but the URL provided returns 404. Any way to bypass this? Currently, I have to kill the process w/ Task Manager (which, btw is another bug - app should gracefully report errors, not get stuck in infinite loops :)). Thanks!

Comment: Sadly, we had another issue with the online feed that drives some of this stuff.  We resolved the issue earlier this evening, and you should be good now.  Sorry!

Comment: No problems Justin, it seems to work now (well, at least the part that converts the folder to a Node.js app - the app itself is not behaving correctly). Thanks!